# How to give same 'get' to multiple jobs in concourse

Tags: yaml, concourse, concourse-git-resource, concourse-s3-resource

Instead of giving the same '- get' to multiple jobs, is there any way that I can optimize my code by giving common '- get', if it is allowed in any way.

Currently, I have given the same code (- get) for different jobs

```
jobs:
- name: Name1
  plan:
  - aggregate:
    - get: anyrepo1
    - get: anyrepo2
  - task: taskhere
    image: anyimage1
    file: file1.yml
- name: Name2
  plan:
  - aggregate:
    - get: anyrepo1
    - get: anyrepo2
  - task: taskhere
    image: anyimage1
    file: file2.yml
```

I am not getting any error, but want to optimize the code

Comment: What do you want to "optimize" exactly ?

Comment: Instead of giving the same '- get' in all jobs, i want to do something that by default gets the '- get'. If there is any way.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to reuse the same thing again and again. In my case i am using a variable "jobs_get_common".

`jobs_get_common: &jobs_get_common
  - get: repo1
  - get: repo2

jobs:
- name: Converge-BHS
  plan:
  - aggregate:
      *jobs_get_common
  - task: anytask
    image: image1
    file: task.yml`

Comment: So the links I provided in my answer actually did help you ?

Comment: Not really. But thanks for the help. :) Much appreciated.

Comment: Strange, since these 2 links contained exactly what you wrote in your own, accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it seems that the "optimization" you are looking for is at the YAML level. You want to reduce YAML duplication. This is independent from Concourse, this technique can be applied to any YAML file.

You can use YAML **merge keys** and **anchors**.

See

- YAML tips and tricks for Concourse CI https://blog.betomorrow.com/yaml-tips-and-tricks-for-concourse-ci-35a3b577a239
- YAML anchor and merge key reference https://camel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yamlref.html

Comment: I am new to concourse, but as per my knowledge, yml just provides the syntax which is understood by concourse. Here I have questioned that is there any way I can edit my yml in such a way that instead of writing `- get: anyrepo1 - get: anyrepo2` for all my jobs, i can write it just once anywhere, which can be understood by concourse.
FYI, no help from links provided.
TIA